# How do we perform a condition after we click on a cell using Eureka

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I'm using the code below:

```
<<< ButtonRow("MyCell") { $0.title = $0.tag $0.presentationMode = .segueName(segueName: "ShowMyScreen", onDismiss: nil) }
```

Now, I need to perform a conditon on click and move only if it's true and show an alert if it's false. Then move if the user clicks on ok from the alert.
How do I do that?

Comment: can you provide some feedback?, did my answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.onCellSelection` closure

**Example code of your requirements**

```
<<< ButtonRow("MyCell") { $0.title = $0.tag
                }.onCellSelection({ (cell, row) in
                    if(yourCondition)
                    {
                       self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowMyScreen", sender: nil)
                    }else{
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "test", message: "test", preferredStyle: .alert)
                        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowMyScreen", sender: nil)
                        })
                        let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)
                        alert.addAction(action)
                        alert.addAction(action2)
                        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                })
```